# Is there any way in which we can compare the values from a column in excel file with the contents of text files using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, text

I was trying to check if we can compare the values present in a single column of excel file to those values in text file, and if the words of the excel file matches the words in text file, we must print the matching word. Ex:-

I have a excel sheet, where column A has names of Players :-

Column 1 :-

Player1
Player2
Player3
.
.
.
.
PlayerN

.Txt file - Contains description of the sports and its legends and has more then 300 words.

The idea is to find if any of the words in column 1 matches the words in text file and if that is the case, we want to print the matching word in a dictionary.

Looking forward to new ideas.

Thanks Team.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show what you have done so far the solve _your_ problem? SO isn't a tutorial replacement. You need to show some effort and then pose questions related to _your_ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

players.xlsx contains a column with

[image]

players.txt contains

```
Player 2 bla bla 

meh meh Player 5
```

```py
import pandas as pd

input_xlsx = 'players.xlsx'
input_txt = 'players.txt'
players = pd.read_excel(input_xlsx,header=None)[0].to_list()
with open(input_txt,'r') as f:
    text = ''.join(f.readlines())
for player in players:
    if player in text:
        print(player)
```

Output is

```
Player 2
Player 5
```